# How to get a Release build without using the publish file?

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, publish-profiles

I have a series of build pipelines setup by someone no longer available. The `Visual Studio Build` steps all have this in their `MSBuild Arguments` field:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:PublishProfile="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\RestApi\Properties\PublishProfiles\VSTS-InPlacePublish.pubxml"
```

This produces a release build but I would like to avoid having to specify the build profile within the source repo of the application; I would like to remove the publish profile and get the same output simply by using the appropriate parameters in the build step.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: If you want to create a web package for deployment you must a publish profile. what you try to achieve?

Comment: I simply want to avoid using the .pubxml file. If all that does is provide parameters for the msbuild task, is there no way to provide those parameters elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe you not must the publish profile, try to remove the `/p:PublishProfile="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\RestApi\Properties\PublishProfiles\VSTS-InPlacePublish.pubxml"` and run the build.

Comment: Tried that. All I got was a debug build output, including all the .cs files, etc.